# NodeJs Database Lookup

Tags: node.js, postgresql, rest, api, express

I'm using a networking website in node using express and postgresql - using the pg npm module - as my database.
I'm now trying to setup user pages like this:

```
...

app.get('/u/:u/', function (req, res) {
    pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
        ...

        client.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =($1)', [req.params.u], function(err, result) {
            ... done(); ...
        });
    });
});

...
```

`req.params.u` returns undefined inside the DB query.

I assume it's because the call back function isn't in the same scope as the app route, how do I get about checking the database like this?

I have a feeling there's a much better way of doing this.

Comment: Specifically, what  exactly do you want to check/test agains the database ?

Comment: `... 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =($1)', [req.params.u] ...`

Comment: Please be more specific. what exactly the issue and where you are stuck?

Comment: `req.params.u` is undefined in the function, im searching usernames...

Comment: @Tobiq . ok checking for the existance of user, true?. But what you wanna do with this information . return it somewhere? assign to a var ? Emit it with an global/scoped Emitter?

Comment: I just want the variable, I may want to respond with a mutated form, can the req / res be accessed inside the connection?

Comment: Can you show your app.js file and how are you requesting this URL from client side?

Comment: Yes, it can be access but why you want as a local variable while it's scope is exist in your code block

Comment: where you want to use your `req` object?

Comment: inside the postgres connection, I want to retrieve user when they goto `http://.../u/username`

Comment: Then what is the issue you can use it in your whole route block.If your params value is undefind then it's another issue

Answer (score 0):

So if the problem is that params gets undefined, the solution should come from something similar to:

```
...

app.get('/u/:u/', function (req, res) {
    var tempReq = req
    pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
    ...

    client.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =($1)',[tempReq.params.u], function(err, result) {
        ... done(); ...
    });
  });
});

...
```

Comment: If rempReq is accessable why isn't req? isit discarded of?

Comment: I suppose that beacuse req is part of the app "this". I'm no Express Guru ( in fact I use Koa) but that is the solution I first try when my vars "magically" disappear

Comment: variables inside `client.query`'s callback are still undefined.

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure to put your `body-parser` code above all the `routes` in your `app.js` file to get `req.body or req.params or req.query` value

```
var app=express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
```

And your `req` object is available in your whole route's scope then you can use it in any where in  this block no need to store in local variable

```
app.get('/u/:u/', function (req, res) {
    pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
    ...

    client.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =($1)',[req.params.u], function(err, result) {
        ... done(); ...
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm not using any middleware, besides the express static folder config, as the last resort for a request, so static files and be used.

Comment: How are you getting req.params value?

Comment: it's native to express, also where does `tempReq.params.u` come from, it was never defined.

Comment: Can you show me from where are you requesting this route?

Comment: It's the first route, it doesn't need any middleware.

Comment: Dude I am not talking about middleware.

Comment: It's the first route, what are you looking for?

Comment: It's first route, but you are calling it from anywhere or not?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If I define `tempRed = req` it work's, but the variables inside `client.query` callback are still undefined

Comment: @Tobig. ok. I was wrong . Forget the whole tempReq issue. But,  can you show us the code that makes the GET request ?

Answer (score 0):

**You can communicate with more than one database at a time too**

**You need ssl first..**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var SSLkey = fs.readFileSync('/local/pem/location/key.pem');
var SSLcert = fs.readFileSync('/local/pem/location/cert.pem');
```

**Now the database code**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const forumdb_db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'dbuser',
    password: 'dbpassword',
    database: 'dbname',
    key: SSLkey,
    cert: SSLcert,
    connectionLimit: 15,
    queueLimit: 30,
    acquireTimeout: 1000
});

const inventory_db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'dbuser',
    password: 'dbpassword',
    database: 'dbname',
    key: SSLkey,
    cert: SSLcert,
    connectionLimit: 15,
    queueLimit: 30,
    acquireTimeout: 1000
});
```

**Connecting to databases**

```
inventory_db.connect((err0) => {
    inventory_db.query("SELECT `bubblebum` FROM `user_inventory` WHERE `index`='1' LIMIT 1;", function(err0, result0, field0) {
        console.log(result0[0].bubblebum);
    });
});

forum_db.connect((err0) => {
    forum_db.query("SELECT `stars` FROM `user_inventory` WHERE `stars`>'100' LIMIT 1;", function(err1, result1, field1) {
        console.log(result1[0].stars);
    });
});
```

*There is one problem with this, You'll be disconnected after a while of inactivity so you should set up an interval to send a quick request every ten seconds to the sql server.*